# Meaning of "identically distributed" when there's only one variable

Tags: regression, bayesian, normal-distribution

From page 8 of Rasmussen's book *Gaussian Processes for Machine Learning*:

[image]

This is all pretty basic...but what do they mean by "identically distributed" in the last sentence? I understand if we have a collection of random variables, we refer to them as identically distributed to mean they all have the same distribution. But here $\epsilon$ is just one random variable. So what does "identically distributed" mean?

Comment: This last sentence is definitely a sloppy formulation. There is no such thing as "identically distributed distribution".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have $n$ observations, $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$. You correspondingly have $n$ noise terms, $\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}^n$. The last sentence means that each separate noise term $\epsilon_i$ is identically distributed and that they are independent.

(In more general situations, the $\epsilon_i$ may *not* be identically distributed, or dependent, e.g., in time series analysis. You need more complex tools in such a situation.)

Answer (score 3):

Identically distributed generally means that each observation of *a variable* was sampled independently from a distribution identical to every other observation *on that variable*.

A simple random walk where $y_{y} = y_{t-1} + 2\mathcal{Bernouli}\left(0.5\right)-1$ is an example of a variable ($y_{t}$) that *is not* i.i.d.: each value of $y_{t}$ depends quite directly on it's immediately prior value, and in fact, the process "remembers" all perturbations to it infinitely. More, the variance of $y_{t}$ is a function of $t$ (in fact, $\sigma^{2}_{y_{t}}=t$), meaning that different values in this time series cannot possible have "the same" distribution.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer. Do I understand correctly that a collection of random variables can be identically distributed and the observations in a sample can be identically distributed, and in the first case identically distributed refers to random variables that have the same probability distribution, whereas in the second case it refers to the fact that each observation was sampled from the same distribution?

Comment: @ColorStatistics Um... yes?